# Aggregation of predictions from ALS Model - SPARK Collaborative filtering

Tags: apache-spark, filtering, collaborative

I'm using the ALS algorithm (implicitPrefs = True) in Spark 2.1.0 for collaborative filtering.

I am wondering if it is possible to aggregate the prediction scores. Lets say for a User1 there are the following predictions:

- Item a: 0.4
- Item b: 0.2
- Item c: 0.1
- Item d: 0.5

In my case items belong to several groups. Lets say Item a and b belong to Group1 and Item c and d to Group 2. Can I now aggregate the predictions? For example by summing them up in order to get the predictions:

- Group1: 0.4 + 0.2 = 0.6
- Group2: 0.5 + 0.1 = 0.6

P.S. Fitting the model on Groups is not wanted, because the correlation between groups and items is not constant. Therefore I don't want to refit the model every time  the correlation changes. I can't figure out of if the aggregation of predictions is mathematical nonsense or not and I am happy for any help.

Comment: if you are using spark-ml, I imagine that the "group" information should be attached to your DF, thus you can always group by user, group and sum

Comment: anyhow, I'm still not sure why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer but I am not asking for how I can sup up my values. I'd rather want to know if its mathematically okay to aggregate the prediction values which I get from the collaborative filtering.